# Find the most similar text in a list of strings

Tags: node.js, typescript, algorithm, sorting, search

First of all, I want to acknowledge that this is perhaps a very sophisticated problem; however, I have not been able to find a definitive answer for it online so I'm looking for suggestions.

Suppose I want to collect a list containing over hundred thousand strings, values of these strings are sentences that a user has typed. The values are added to the list as soon as a user types a new message. For example:

```json
["Hello world!", "Good morning, my name is John", "Good morning, everyone"]
```

But I also want to have a timeout for each string so if they are not repeated within 5 min, they should be removed, so I change it to following format:

```json
[{message:"Hello world!", timeout: NodeJS.Timeout, count: 1}, {message:"Good morning, my name is John", timeout: NodeJS.Timeout, count: 1}, {message:"Good morning, everyone", timeout: NodeJS.Timeout, count: 1}]
```

Now suppose a user types the following message:

`Good morning, everyBODY`
I want to compare this string to all the messages in list and if one is 70% or more similar, update the count of that message, otherwise insert it as a new message. For this message for example, the application should update the count for `Good morning, everyone` to be equal to 2.

Since users can type a lot of messages in a short amount of time, the algorithm must also support fast insertion, searching, and deleting after the timeout.

What is the best way to implement this? or are there any libraries to help me with this?

NOTE: The strings do not need to be in an array, any data structure would work.

**The main purpose of this algorithm is to detect similar messages when the count reaches a predefined value. For example `warning: Over 5 users typed messages similar to "Hello everybody" within 5 minutes`**

I have looked at B-Trees, Nearest Neighbor, etc but I can't figure out what would be the best solution.

**Update:**
I plan on using Levenshtein distance for string similarity, however the main problem is how to apply that to a list of strings in most time efficient way, without having to check every single string every time a new message is added.

Comment: Good that you found an Edit Distance algorithm to use. That's the way to go. Regarding the efficient search, I'd treat it like a web search engine. Split each string into words and put them in an index, perhaps using a Trie data structure. Then when a new sentence comes in, use the index to narrow down which strings to compare it to. Maybe only consider strings that have at least 3 of the words used in the new string. Just some ideas.

Comment: I’m wondering if BK-trees would be helpful here? Or maybe some other metric space tree?

Comment: It would seem to me that if you are measuring distance you can't avoid comparing each new string with every string in the list, so there is no data structure that can help you. The only thing that would help is some sort of value you can calculate for each value that has a kind of statistical profile of the string (similar to @Guy Coders answer)

Comment: @SilverRampart if the OP manages to embed their strings into some metric space, then finding neighbors can be done without having to iterate over all the elements. That could also be an approach.

Comment: I am still not clear what your end goal is, but maybe you should look for a search engine like elasticsearch, this might be [helpful](https://www.elastic.co/blog/text-similarity-search-with-vectors-in-elasticsearch) to give you context.

Answer (score 5):

## Levenshtein distance

Unlike the other answer I think Levenshtein distance is perfectly capable of dealing with spelling mistakes. Indeed, Levenshtein and LevXenshtein only have Levenshtein distance 1, and thus can be concluded to likely be the same message.

However, if you want to use this distance, you will have to compute the distance between the new message and every message stored, every time a new message comes in. There is likely no way around this.

Unfortunately there is no real useful pre-processing you can do for this.

## Other possibilities

If you can find a way to map every message to a fixed-size vector, you can use essentially any *nearest neighbor search* technique. I suggest doing so.

This leaves us with two problems to solve. Generating the fixed-length vector, and doing the search.

### Fixed-size vector representation

There are multiple ways of doing this, all with their own set of drawbacks. I'll specifically mention two, but it will depend on your architecture and data which method is best for you.

First, you could go the machine-learning way. You could map every word to a pre-trained vector with [fastText](https://fasttext.cc/), average the words in the message, and use that as your vector. The drawbacks of this method are that it will ignore word order, and it will work less well if the words used tend to be *very* informal. If your messages have their own culture to them (such as for example Twitch chat) you would have to retrain these vectors instead of using pre-trained ones.

Alternatively, you could use the structure of the text directly, and make an occurrence vector of [bigrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigram). That is, jot down how often every 2-character combination occurs in a message. This is fairly robust, but has the drawback that the vectors will become relatively large.

Regardless, these are just two options, and it's impossible to tell what method is ideal for you. Unless of course someone has a brilliant idea.

### Nearest neighbor search

Given that we have fixed length vectors, we can now do nearest neighbor search. As you've probably found, there are once again [many different methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search#Methods) for this, all with their own drawbacks. Exhausting, I know.

I'll choose to discuss three categories.

1. **Approximate search:** This method may seem a little silly, but it could be what you want. Specifically, [Locality-sensitive hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing) is essentially just making some hashing function where "similar" vectors are likely to end up in the same bucket. You could then do anything you want, such as Levenshtein, with all of the other members of the bucket, because there should not be too many of them. The advantage of such an approximate algorithm is that it can be fast, and with some smart hashing you don't even need fixed-length vectors. A downside, of course, is that it is not guaranteed to work.
2. **Exact search:** We can also choose to instead solve the problem of [Fixed-radius near neighbors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-radius_near_neighbors). That is, find the points within some distance of the target point. You could do this by mapping vectors to integers (if they aren't already) and simply checking every lattice point within the distance you want to search. The primary drawback here is that the search time grows very fast not with the number of points, but with the number of dimensions of the vector. This method would necessitate small vectors.
3. **Fancy datastructures:** This seems to me most likely to be the right solution. Unfortunately you have a lot of letter-trees. You mention B-trees, but there's also [R-trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_tree), [R+-Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R+_tree), [R*-Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R*_tree), [X-Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-tree), and that's just the direct descendants of the R-tree. With the risk of missing the trees for the forest, I'd suggest taking a look at the [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree). It can do nearest neighbor search in logarithmic time, as well as insertion and deletion.

Comment: A similar but faster alternative to Levenshtein could be a simple LCS distance. Another more customizable "distance" on strings are the Needleman-Wunsch and the Smith-Waterman algorithms. All those (including Levenshtein) are very similar.

Comment: @m.raynal I think trying out other distance metrics has value, but note that none of those are all that much faster to compute. Like Levenshtein, they're all O(nm), and more importantly require pairwise comparison, not allowing search. I'm personally also a little wary of using NW and SW because they're designed specifically for gene alignment which can have important differences to natural language string alignment, but perhaps that's just my personal preference.

Comment: LCS is much, much faster to compute in practice, by several orders of magnitude. Even if the `O` bound is similar (`O(n*p)` where p is the number of 'matches' between the two string and `n` the size of the smaller string), there exist many algorithms (mostly in bioinformatics) which have incredible runtimes, uncomparable to the classic DP implementation.

Comment: As for SW & NW, they can be very useful for some natural language applications (for instance, one can consider that adjacent letters on a keyboard are not as different as letters further away to detect mistyping). They're quite underrated when it comes to other applications than gene alignment, but in the end they're just plain generalizations of LCS and Levenshtein.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on how to create fixed size bigrams from text? Since variable sized strings will yield variable sized bigram vectors.

Comment: Bigram vector have a fixed size of `S²` where `S` is the size of your alphabet. For instance, if you alphabet is `ab` and your string `'aabaa'` then your bigram vector values will be the following: `aa: 2, ab: 1, ba: 1, bb: 0`. So they're vector of size `S²`, each field with values in `N`

Comment: Well in that case, this method will be practically impossible to implement assuming users can use any character in any language or any symbol. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @Aiden It depends on what messages tend to look like of course, but you don't have to take every symbol into account. You can choose to do only, say, 26 letters of the basic Latin alphabet and whitespace/punctuation, and simply ignore the rest. You could even choose to map some different symbols to the same character, {á, à, ã, a} -> a, or even more drastically {c,k} -> k. Doing something like this might get good results, but would take some serious time feature crafting and testing.

Answer (score 1):

You want to covert all of the words to their [Soundex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) value.

Then you need a database for the soundex values that ranks the importance of the word in the sentence, e.g. `the` should probably get 0. The more information the word carries the higher its value.

Then sort the words in the sentence into a list of integers.

Use the list of integers as the key to find similar sentences.

Since the key is a list of integers a [Rose tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_tree) should work as data structure.

While some may suggest measuring using something like [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) that presupposes that the sentences have no spelling mistakes or such. You need something that is flexible enough to deal with human error.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/). Which has their own ranking algorithm rates each matching record on several criteria (such as the number of typos or the geo-distance), to which they individually assign a integer value score.

I would totally take a loook on it, since they have Search-as-you-type and different Ranking algorithm criterias.

https://blog.algolia.com/search-ranking-algorithm-unveiled/

Answer (score 1):

I think Search Engine like [`SOLR`](https://lucene.apache.org) or [`Elastic Search`](https://www.elastic.co/) are best fit for your problem.

You have to create single collection in which you can store data as you have mention in the question after that you just have to add data to solr and search it in the solr search with your time limit.